# Trouble with Android SDK and ADB

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, adb

I'm trying to load my apk into the SDK and when I type "android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb install RaceTones.apk" in the command line, all I get is:

Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Keith Baldwin>cd c:\

C:>android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb install RaceTones.apk
can't find 'RaceTones.apk' to install

I've checked and I do have that apk file in the platform-tools directory. I'm running Windows XP and have the latest SDK. Also, I'm running the emulator as I don't own a Droid device. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

`adb` is looking for the APK in the current directory, from your example, `c:\`.

So either move the APK to `c:\` or change the current directory `c:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\` and run the adb command again.